# How to construct a custom-made matrix conditional on a set of rules?

Tags: matrix, function-construction

The following code does what I intend to achieve; however, it is too cluttered for a simple matrix operation. I like to reduce the code to a `one-line code` as a function that accepts a matrix as an input with some elements being negative such as `m0`.

```
ClearAll[m0, m1, m2, m3, m22, m0N];

Row[{
  (m0 = {{1, 2, -3, 1}, {0, 2, -1, 5}, {-1, 2, 3, 1}, {0, 1, 2, 4}}) //
    MatrixForm, Spacer[50],
  (m1 = {{1, 2, -3, 1}, {0, 2, -1, 5}, {-1, 2, 3, 1}, {0, 1, 2, 4}}) //
    MatrixForm
  }]

(m2 = Table[
    If[m0[[i, j]] > 0, m0[[i, j]] = 0, m0[[i, j]]], {i, 
     Length@m0}, {j, Length@m0}
    ]) // MatrixForm

(m3 = (-1)*Transpose@m2) // MatrixForm

(m22 = Table[
    If[m1[[i, j]] < 0, m1[[i, j]] = 0, m1[[i, j]]], {i, 
     Length@m1}, {j, Length@m1}
    ]) // MatrixForm

(m0N = m22 + m3) // MatrixForm
```

The result of the above code is shown step-by-step.

[image]

Comment: `Clear[m0, m0N]; m0N[m0_?MatrixQ] := 
 Clip[m0, {0, Infinity}] - Transpose@Clip[m0, {-Infinity, 0}]`

Comment: @Bob Hanlon: A very compact and speedy code! Why do not you give it as an answer rather than a comment?

Comment: I consider it too brief for an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope that the following will be useful a bit, and fun. There's a small flexing bit.

So, the question essentially boils down to the following two tasks:

> 1. How do I delete all negative elements of a matrix?

> 2. How do I delete all positive elements of a matrix?

Then taking the [**Transpose**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Transpose.html) and adding them is straightforward.

> 1. How do I delete all negative elements of a matrix?

You have the following options

```
bobhanlon = Clip[m0, {0, Infinity}];
jdp = (m0 /. _?(# < 0 &) :> 0);
bmf01 = m0 /. _?Internal`SyntacticNegativeQ -> 0;(*unnecessary flexing*)
bmf02 = m0 /. _?Negative -> 0;
bmf03 = m0 UnitStep[m0];
bmf04 = Replace[m0, _?Negative -> 0, {-1}];
bmf05 = m0 HeavisideTheta[m0];
bmf06 = Map[Max[0, #] &, m0, {-1}];
bmf07 = Ramp@m0;
bobhanlon == jdp == bmf01 == bmf02 == bmf03 == bmf04 == bmf05 == 
bmf06 == bmf07
```

> `True`

> 2. How do I delete all positive elements of a matrix?

Normal people would do

```
bobhanlonneg = Clip[m0, {-Infinity, 0}];
jdpneg = m0 /. _?(# > 0 &) :> 0;
bmgneg01 = m0 /. _?Positive -> 0;
bmgneg02 = Replace[m0, _?Positive -> 0, {-1}];
bmgneg03 = Map[Min[0, #] &, m0, {-1}];
bobhanlonneg == jdpneg == bmgneg01 == bmgneg02 == bmgneg03
```

> `True`

And people with issues like me would tell you, that you can, also, take the minus of the original matrix, delete the negative elements, and take another minus to keep the original sign.

**Yes, my brain is not functioning properly and we can move on.**

```
negneg01 = -Clip[-m0, {0, Infinity}];
negneg02 = -(-m0 /. _?(# < 0 &) :> 0);
negneg03 = -(-m0 /. _?Internal`SyntacticNegativeQ -> 0);
negneg04 = -(-m0 /. _?Negative -> 0);
negneg05 = -(-m0 UnitStep[-m0]);
negneg06 = -Replace[-m0, _?Negative -> 0, {-1}];
negneg07 = -(-m0 HeavisideTheta[-m0]);
negneg08 = -Map[Max[0, #] &, -m0, {-1}];
negneg09 = -Ramp@(-m0);
bobhanlonneg == jdpneg == bmgneg01 == bmgneg02 == bmgneg03 == 
negneg01 == negneg02 == negneg03 == negneg04 == negneg05 == negneg06 
== negneg07 == negneg08 == negneg09
```

> `True`

And now, you can combine all the above and have that many alternatives.

Answer (score 4):

EDITED in response to comment.

Your input:

```
m0 = {{1, 2, -3, 1}, {0, 2, -1, 5}, {-1, 2, 3, 1}, {0, 1, 2, 4}};
```

The function definition:

```
m0N[mat_?MatrixQ] := (mat /. _?(#<0&) :> 0) -(Transpose[mat/. _?(#>0&):>0]);
```

The idea is to use a replacement rule and pattern to identify and zero out selected terms.

The result. I omitted MatrixForm to avoid having to paste the BoxForms.

```
m0N[m0]

(* {{1, 2, 1, 1}, {0, 2, 0, 5}, {3, 3, 3, 1}, {0, 1, 2, 4}} *)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Note that `m0` and `m1` are identical. I introduced `m1` as a dummy matrix only because of computational ease. My goal is to use a single matrix `m0` for the adjustment.